# SQLite - could not execute statement due to a constraint failed (19 constraint failed)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, insert

I'm starting working with SQLite and Javascript for a PhoneGap aplication, the thing here is that I'm using a web service and adding rows to a local sqlite database. In this case, the length of items I want to insert is 1016 exactly, but it only inserts less than 100, and "could not execute statement due to a constraint failed (19 constraint failed)" keeps showing up.

This is part of the code:

```
function onSuccessCustomers(data){
    alert("CLIENTES: " + data.length);
    $.each(data, function(i, item) { 
         database.executeQuery("INSERT INTO cliente1 (codcli) VALUES ('" + item.CODCLI + "')");                           
    });
}
```

Here the alert shows "CLIENTES: 1016" and thats CORRECT!, the foreach goes on and on 1016 times, too. But when I check the table, only a few rows have been inserted.

Here's the executeQuery function:

```
function executeQuery (query) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        getInstance().transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function(tx, r) {
                deferred.resolve(r);
            }, function(tx, e) {
                alert(e.message);
                deferred.fail(e);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    };
```

Here is when the message shows up. Any ideas??

Comment: What constraints are defined on that table?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I face similar situation and all I did to resolve it is to drop the Table and create it again.
What happened was that i was trying to insert into a column that does not exist in the table after i edited the columns to a new one..